# how to sample the bitmap for memory management in android?

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, image-scaling

i have made a demo for image editing,I am facing issue when i pass the image to another activity(Grow heap size),and my app crashed,Please tell me how cani sample and resize my bitmap directly (not from resources) to solve memory issue ,My code is as below:
**code**

```
if (Global.photo_editor_bitmap != null) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                Global.photo_editor_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,
                        100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                i = new Intent(PhotoEditor.this, Enhance.class);
                i.putExtra("bitmap_image", byteArray);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Image", 1).show();
            }

    static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        int inSampleSize = 1; // Default subsampling size
        // See if image raw height and width is bigger than that of required
        // view
        if (options.outHeight > reqHeight || options.outWidth > reqWidth) {
            // bigger
            final int halfHeight = options.outHeight / 2;
            final int halfWidth = options.outWidth / 2;
            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and
            // keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }

    static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);
        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }
```

I got solution of decodebitmapFromresources,But my bitmap is available,SO how to use this direclty.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem the app gets crashed and showing message in log for heap size, allocation size and bitmap size, what i have done is checked the device width & height and on the basis of that scaled the bitmap or calculate sample size.

```
int screenHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
```

get the width and height and then put it in reqWidth and reqHeight

Comment: Hello,thanks for reply,But i dont know how to pass my bitmap in function,decodeSampledBitmapFromResource,As it required resource and i have already bitmap available.how to pass my bitmap to it?

Comment: How you storing bitmap in Global.photo_editor_bitmap??? because you are sending this bitmap as byteArray to another activity